Stop File Dialog from Opening When Workbook is Open
I am successfully using the following code to copy cell contents from one workbook to another. The code works as intended when the source workbook is closed. However, when the source workbook is open, I get a file dialog box asking me to choose the file. I can close the dialog without having to choose the file and the code still works, but I want to not have the file selection dialog box open at all.
Sub CollectExternalData()
On Error GoTo codeErr

'---> PURPOSE: Loads cell data from another spreadsheet

Dim sPath as string
Dim rTarget As Range

'---> Path where the spreadsheet is located:
sPath = "='C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyFolder\[FileName.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1:$A$20"

'---> Where to put the copied data:
Set rTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")

'---> Get the cell data to be copied:
rTarget.FormulaArray = sPath

'---> Insert the copied cell data:
rTarget.Formula = rTarget.Value

codeExit:
   Exit Sub
codeErr:
   Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume codeExit
End Sub


I would use PowerQuery to get that data into the target sheet. It will be more performant than having a linked sheet

Try adding Application.DisplayAlerts = False at the begining and Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end?

I cannot reproduce your issue. What is your excel version?

I'm using Excel 365

Yes, adding Application.DisplayAlerts = False did the trick. Thank you!
